# Is $f(x,t) = \sin (x) e^{-tx}$ in $L^1([0, \infty) \times [0, \infty))$?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

I have the integral $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \sin (x) e^{-tx} \ dt \ dx.$ I want to switch the order of integration using Fubini's Theorem, which requires that the integrand be absolutely integrable.

I tried the following estimate: $|\sin (x) e^{-tx}| \leq e^{-tx}$.

However, $\displaystyle\iint_{[0, \infty) \times [0, \infty)} e^{-tx} = \infty$.

Comment: Although you cannot use Fubini's theorem for the infinite limits, (see the answer below where the integrand is showed to be not in $L^1$), you can still replace the order of integration, because the integrand is continuous, and in particular $L^1$ on any finite interval. Compute the integral (in any order you like) on finite intervals of integration and then let the limits tend to infinity.

Comment: @uniquesolution The continuity of the integrand is not a sufficient condition to allow the change of the order of integration. The function $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\sin (\pi \frac{x+1}{y+1}) &\text{ for } 0 \le x < 2y+1\\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$ is a counterexample.

Comment: This is not a counterexample, as $f(x,y)$ is not continuous along the $y$-axis unless $y=0$. For example, $f(0,1)=\sin(\pi/2)=1$, but according to your definition, $f(-\delta,1)=0$ for all $\delta>0$. Note that I suggested interchanging the order of integration on *finite* intervals, which is possible for continuous functions. For a proof, see https://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/217.1.13f/217-20131113.pdf

Comment: Where are speaking of functions defined on $[0,+\infty) \times [0,+\infty)$ here. So your comments is just irrelevant...

Comment: Well, I can't see how your example is a counterexample to anything. My comment suggested interchanging the order of integration for a continuous function on finite intervals. I really don't see the relevance of your example to this fact, even if we speak about $[0,\infty)\times[0,\infty)$ only. I did not claim that for *every* continuous function the double infinite integral will converge *because* you can change integration on finite intervals. I *did* point out that in *this* case, you can verify that the result of the improper integral can be achieved in either way of integration.

Comment: Then, your initial comment is poorly formulated. It is not because the function is continuous that you can change the order of integration. You should just have said that it is true for this specific example. This has nothing to do with continuity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31224/discussion-between-mathcounterexamples-net-and-uniquesolution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x,t) = \sin (x) e^{-tx}$ would belong to $L^1([0, \infty) \times [0, \infty))$, $$\int_o^\infty \left( \int_0^\infty \vert f(x,t) \vert dt \right) dx$$ would be finite.

However $$\int_o^\infty \left( \int_0^\infty \vert \sin x \ e^{-xt} \vert dt \right) dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{\vert \sin x \vert }{x} dx$$ diverges. So $f$ does not belong to $L^1$.

Comment: True. Still, the double integral in question converges to $\pi/2$, and it can be computed in either order of integration.

Comment: I agree. But it's not the question of the OP.

Comment: What do you think the OP is interested in more, the integrand being an $L^1$ function, or a reason to interchange the order of integration?

Comment: I don't know! I don't read in his thoughts. At least the title is pretty clear.

Comment: You are both right! I wanted to know both things! :)

Comment: You certainly don't read his thoughts, but you should read his questions.

Comment: Please keep your advices for yourself. Moreover when OP is acknowledging there was two different topics covered in the title and question.

Comment: This double integral converges, as an iterated integral, to $\pi/2$, regardless of which variable is integrated first. In either order the inner integral is absolutely convergent, but only in the order "$x$ first, then $t$" is the outer integral absolutely convergent. In the other order the outer integral is "improper" (at infinity).

Answer (score 0):

$\int e^{-tx}\mathrm{d}t = \frac 1 x$ , so your $\iint$ collapse to $\int \frac {\sin(x)} x \mathrm{d}x$

Comment: Then use Tonelli's theorem.